# Monte Carlo Method for approximating conditional expectation

Tags: r, monte-carlo, conditional-expectation

I would like to compute E[X | X > a] for X ~ Gamma(.) using a Monte Carlo (simulation) apporoach. Any idea how I would go about it? 
I have a method but I am not sure if it's correct or consistent:

```
a=200
A = sapply(1:100, function(i){sim = rgamma(10**3,shape=10,scale=20)
    sim = sim[sim>a]
    return(sum(sim)/length(sim))
})
```

Plotting A, there seems to be a lot of variance as shown[image: Histogram of A]

Comment: @Xi'an How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides the obvious generation from a Gamma generator until the outcome is larger than a, as in your R code and the (inefficient)

```
gene=rep(0,N)
for (i in 1:N){
   x=rgamma(1,b,c)
   while (x<a) x=rgamma(1,b,c)
   gene[i]=x}
```

or the slightly improved

```
gama=rgamma(N,b,c)
gene=gama[gama>a]
while (length(gene)<N){
  gama=rgamma(N,b,c)
  gene=c(gene,gama[gama>a])}
gene=gene[1:N]
```

[which both may suffer from unacceptable running time when $a$ gets large enough], there exist optimised truncated Gamma generators, as an accept-reject algorithm in [Philippe (1996)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1018534102043). If one is not concerned by a high precision, inverting the cdf as in

```
Fa=pgamma(a,b,c)
gene=qgamma(runif(N,Fa,1),b,c)
```

or (when a is too large)

```
Fa=pgamma(a,b,c,low=FALSE)
gene=qgamma(1-runif(N,0,Fa),b,c)
```

works as well.

An illustration of the limitations of the "repeat until x>a" approach is provided by moving from a=200 to a=2000

```
> pgamma(2000,shape=10,scale=20,lower.tail=FALSE)
[1] 1.125347e-31
```

since it would take an average of 10³¹ attempts to produce one acceptance.