# Closed form Conditional Expectation of Gamma Distributed Variable

Tags: r, conditional-expectation

I am trying to solve a missing values problem using EM algorithm and I am having trouble deriving closed form solution in the Expectation step. Say we have gamma distributed variables $X^{(1)}...X^{(200)}$ ~ $Gamma(k=15,\theta=15)$.
I want to find a closed form solution to $E[X | X>200]$. I tried doing a Monte Carlo approximation to the Expectation step ([found help here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/337585/monte-carlo-method-for-approximating-conditional-expectation)) but the EM algorithm is unstable (no consistent convergence robust to initial values). So I want to know if analytical solution is possible?

So far what I have is, we can write $P(X) = P(X | X>200)*P(X>200)$
P(X>200) is just `pgamma(200,shape=15,scale=15,lower.tail=F)` which gives 0.640715.
So $P(X | X>200) = P(X;X>200)/0.640715$ But I don't know how to evaluate this further and plug it into the E[.] equation.

Answer (score 1):

A general formula for the conditional expectation of a gamma random variable is given by $$E \left[ X|X>t \right]=\frac{\alpha \beta \left[1-F_{\alpha+1,\beta } \left( t \right) \right]}{1-F_{\alpha,\beta } \left( t \right)},$$ where $\alpha$ is the shape, $\beta$ is the scale, and $F_{\alpha,\beta}$ is the cdf.

When the shape parameter is an integer, the complement of the cdf of a gamma random variable is a product of an exponential term and a polynomial. In your case, using $t=200$ and your shape and scale values, the formula becomes $$E \left[ X|X>200 \right]=\frac{\alpha \beta \ \sum_{j=0}^{15}\left( \frac{40}{3}  \right)^j / j! }{\sum_{j=0}^{14}\left( {\frac{40}{3}} \right)^j / j! }=\alpha \beta \ \left( 1+ \frac{\left( \frac{{40}}{3} \right)^{15} / 15!} {\sum_{j=0}^{14}\left( {\frac{40}{3}} \right)^j / j! } \right)\approx 257.55  $$